# Solrnet: problem when search field value is query operator (eq. or, and)

Tags: c#, solrnet

To be more precise I will be working with example...

Clean query is: (type:77 AND (zipCode:12345 OR name:OR))

When querying on Solr Admin page this throws exception:

org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse...

So on Solr Admin page I changed query to:

(type:"77" AND (zipCode:"12345" OR name:"OR"))

which worked as a charm

Now I have a problem to do the same stuff with solrnet. I am using SolrQueryByField class for querying. When I am working with

new SolrQueryByField("name", "OR")

I get Solrnet.Exceptions.InvalidFieldException which is in accordance with Solr Admin page, but when I am working with

new SolrQueryByField("name", "\"OR\"")

I get wrong results. By inspecting network traffic I found out that http get request is different (for brevity only name field name and value are given):

name%3A%22OR%22     => from Solr Admin page

name%3a%5c%22OR%5c%22     => from solrnet

My question is: what sholud I do to prevent solrnet from adding %5C (backslash) to query string?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SolrQueryByField` produces quoted/escaped values. If you have some special case where this is not desirable (such as this case) you can use `SolrQuery`, e.g. :

```
Query.Field("type").Is(77) && (Query.Field("zipCode").Is("12345") || Query.Simple("name:\"OR\""))
```

Comment: I would like to do so but I do not have "15 reputation" which are needed to upvote :( I accepted the answer. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try to pass the string array that contains multiple field names and search text in the below method. It will return the solrnet query for search with multiple filed name with OR condition.

```
public ISolrQuery BuildQuery(string[] SearchFields, string SearchText)
    {
        try
        {
            AbstractSolrQuery firstQuery = new SolrQueryByField(SearchFields[0], SearchText) { Quoted = false };

            for (var i = 1; i < parameters.SearchFields.Length; i++)
            {
                firstQuery = firstQuery || new SolrQueryByField(SearchFields[i], SearchText) { Quoted = false };
            }

            return firstQuery;
        }
```