# SolrNet ANDs and ORs with SolrQuery objects and eDisMax

Tags: solrnet

I have been building Solr queries manually as strings and passing them to SolrNet.  The queries can be complicated combinations of ANDs and ORs like this:

```
 _query_:"field1:[1 TO 10] OR 
          field2:[1 TO 10] OR 
          field3:[1 TO 10]"
  AND  
 _query_:"field4:(keyword)"
  AND  
 _query_:"field5:(keyword)"
```

This was working well, but looking into the API for SolrNet, I see there are objects I could use for each clause and then pull these objects together to form the complete query.  I would much rather implement this with that approach than build and concatenate the strings.

(I should mention that I am using the eDisMax parser, which allows me to use the `_query_` field as you see above.)

The API is well documented for [ANDs and ORs](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#query-operators) but I need to have the ANDs and ORs grouped to handle the sitations like above--things like (a OR b) AND (c OR d).  Has anyone done this before with SolrNet?  Thanks!

UPDATE:  I found an example that I think combines ANDs and ORs with parenthesis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042259/solrnet-problem-when-search-field-value-is-query-operator-eq-or-and).  Unfortunately, this assumes that I know the structure of the query in advance.  Instead, I will be creating a SolrNet query dynamically based on user input, so I can't hardcode a pattern like (a) && (b || c).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/solrnet/SI8pwin1YvY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should give you what you are looking for:

```
var queryList = new List<ISolrQuery>();
if (condition1)
    queryList.Add(new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(new List<ISolrQuery>
                {
                    new SolrQueryByRange<decimal>("field1", 1, 10),
                    new SolrQueryByRange<decimal>("field2", 1, 10),
                    new SolrQueryByRange<decimal>("field3", 1, 10)
                }, "OR"));
if (condition2)
    queryList.Add(new SolrQueryByField("field3", keyword));

if (condition3)
    queryList.Add(new SolrQueryByField("field4", keyword));

var finalQuery = new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queryList, "AND");
```