# Constructing complex SolrQuery objects containing ANDs/ORs using SolrJ

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

How do I construct a complex SolrQuery object that contains ANDs/ORs using SolrJ?

Example:

```
SolrQuery ss = new SolrQuery().setQuery("(a:1 AND (b:2 OR -c:3))");
```

This will of course work but instead of one long query string, I want to recursively build up the query. Here's what I tried:

```
    SolrQuery sq0 = new SolrQuery().setParam("a", "1");
    SolrQuery sq1 = new SolrQuery().setParam("b", "2").setParam("-c", "3");
    SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery();
    sq.add(sq0);
    sq.add(sq1);
```

That doesn't work because `sq` is equivalent to `a=1&b=2&-c=3` which is not what I want.

Here's a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610897/solrnet-ands-and-ors-with-solrquery-objects-and-edismax) that was asked in the context of SolrNet. I'm wondering if something similar is possible with SolrJ as well.

Comment: Regarding: `(a:1 AND (b:2 OR -c:3))`, you say that will work.  You sure about that though?  Generally, queries like `b:2 OR -c:3` don't work quite like one would expect.  I would rather expect that query to also get results equivalent to `a=1&b=2&-c=3`.  Could be something I'm missing though, do you see that query working correctly *in practice*?

Comment: Yes, `setQuery("(a:1 AND (b:2 OR -c:3))")` does seem to work for me. The URL shows up as `/select?q=(a:1%20AND%20(b:2%20OR%20-c:3))` and I get the expected set of docs. Of course, the spaces are necessary for the query to be parsed correctly. 

Generally speaking, I'm looking for a way to construct AND/OR operators using SolrJ. If that's not possible, then I'm hoping that there's something equivalent to it.